# How to create safari extension for iOS?

Tags: ios, safari

I found a way to create Safari extension [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariAppExtension_PG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017319-CH15-SW1)
but this is only for 'OS X'. I wonder if there is a way to create one for the iOS.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The only type of extension you can create on iOS is a [content blocker](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ContentBlocker.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not make extensions for mobile safari.

On the other hand you can add bookmarklets.
The article is pretty old but it should do the trick: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way--net-18154